# Create external table but warehose empty?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hive v0.13

My data is stored in hdfs, I use create `"CREATE external TABLE"` to create a table for those data.  Everything works fine, I can issue `"select"` statements.  The question is under the warehouse directory `(hive.metastore.warehouse.dir)`, I don't see any `files/data` get added, is this normal?  I know with `"external"` table data will not get copy to warehouse directory but shouldn't there be table meta data be stored under there?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a internal table hive creates a directory with table name under the directory you have specified in `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`. For me it `/apps/hive/warehouse.`

Suppose you have created a table name `test_tbl` then there will be a directory `/apps/hive/warehouse/test_tbl`and hive store metadata into mysql or your configured RDBMS for store metadata.and when you load data using `LOAD DATA INPATH` command into this directory.

But in `external table` you specify a location in your create statement hence hive doesn't create any directory in default warehouse directory because you have already provided the location. it just store metadata information in `RDBMS`

You can directly load data into that location using `hdfs dfs -put` command and hive will treat that data for the table which is associated with that particular directory. Hence it is expected behavior for external table.

Comment: Thanks.  But where is my "RDBMS" in this case?  I didn't installed any database.

Comment: Which distribution you are using. Is it your single node image? By default hive comes configured to use Derby as the metastore. Hence it is using `Derby` to store metadata.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a external table Metadata will be genrally stored in the RDBMS i.e., in metastore database and the data which you insert or load will be stored in the directory.

either it is an external or managed table metadata will always be in RDBMS when you query on any table hive will actually get the table schema from metastore and data from HDFS evaluates the schema with data and displays.

So, there wont be any metadata created in warehouse for external tables.